# How to store data in JSON object

Tags: jquery, json

I have data with the following structure:

**Unique ID (int) | First Name (string) | Last Name (string) | Pct (double)**

A set of the data might look something like this:

1 | John | Hancock | 49.5 
2 | John | Hancock | 95.0 
3 | Jane | Hancock | 89.5 
4 | Jane | Hancock | 73.5 
5 | Jane | Hancock | 96.5 
6 | Fred | Flintstone | 45.8

What I need is to store this data on the client-side so that it is accessible to the browser and can be manipulated using jQuery.

For example, I have a dropdown (select) on the page that has three values in it:

1) Low Percentile
2) Mid Percentile
3) High Percentile

When the user selects one of the values in the dropdown then I need to be able to select items from my data above that qualify for the selected value. For example, if they select the Low Percentile value then I need to retrieve all of the items from the data that have a percentage less than 60%.

I'm fairly versatile with jQuery, but I've never used it to store anything of this sort for client-side retrieval. Can I somehow store this data in JSON objects on the client-side, which in turn can be selected from and manipulated at will?

Comment: Are you familiar with how to store this data as a javascript object? If you are jQuery has built in functions for converting javascript objects to JSON and JSON objects to javascript objects. A JSON "OBJECT" is a string serialized.

Comment: Short answer = yes you can. I'm not really sure what else you're expecting from your question

Comment: @Leeish - No, I'm not sure how to store it as a javascript object. I've used JSON to store data in HTML tags (and the actual data-* attribute), but I've never actually stored data in sort of javascript object that persists through the life of the page. This is where I'm getting stuck at. Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Just for the life of the page? So, you want to store complex data in a global variable?

Comment: @Jagd you should read up on JSON usage as it sounds like you don't need to use JSON here. If you are just looking to manipulate data all client side and don't need to send it anywhere, you could probably just stick with javascript objects.

Comment: @Blazemonger - Yes. The data will need to be loaded into a variable during the page load, and that variable should be accessible when other jQuery events (such as the change event of the select) need to use it.

Comment: @Leeish - Okay, gotcha. I'm more familiar with JSON and jQuery then javascript - sad, I know - which is why my first inclination was to store the data in JSON objects of some sort. Really what I'm getting at here is how do I store the data on the client-side so that it can be selected from and used during various events that can occur on the page (such as the change event of the select).

Comment: My edit to my answer below should provide you with the direction to go then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically:

```
var javascriptObject = $.parseJSON(jsonString);

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(javascriptObject);
```

JavaScript is much like any other OOP.

```
var foo = {}; //NEW Object
foo.bar = 1;
foo.bars = 2;
foo.bar.date = 3;
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(foo);
//jsonString is now a "JSON Object" that holds the data found in object foo.
console.log(jsonString); //To see what it looks like.
```

However if all of this is for client side usage, just stick with JavaScript objects. No need to convert them to JSON. JSON objects are really for sending data to other sources as they are strings. Usually used in AJAX requests.

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var globalObject = {};
    globalObject.foo = 1;
    globalObject.bar = 2;

    $(el).change(function(){
        globalObject.foo = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

Comment: What's the scope of the javascriptObject though? Assume that I load it up during the page load for example, how do I make it so that it'll be available to me during the change event of the select?

Comment: It can be whatever scope you want. I just added an edit where globalObject is your javascript object you will need throughout your page processing. It will be available anywhere. You should probably do some more `Hello World` stuff with javascript to get a better grasp on OOP in javascript. You'll need a firm grasp of closure or your'll be back asking questions why your values didn't change when you thought they would. Not being mean, it's just I've seen the same questions asked on here 100 times.

Answer (score 2):

JSON stands for Javascript Object Notation.  If you're familiar with Objects, you should be able to work with it.

For your example, I would probably save the variable as an Array of objects (because it is numbered first).  Hopefully you wouldn't mind reassigning the numbers to zero-based increments (0, 1, 2...).

Perhaps you could do something like this instead, if you want to save it client-side:

```
var data = [
{ fname : "John", lname : "Hancock", value : 49.5 },
{ fname : "John", lname : "Hancock", value : 95.0 }
];
```

That's just the first two as an example.  You could then iterate over the array with a for loop `for(var i=0, count = data.length; i < count; i++)` , and do something with the data if `data[i].value < 60`.

jQuery's got a nice function called [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) that you could just as easily use too.  Also, you could have the JSON saved in a .json file and called by [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), if you have a need for that.  Both could be good starts in learning about this.

Comment: That's **not** JSON, it's a javascript object literal. There's a big difference.

Comment: What's not JSON?  I said in the answer that I would do something different.

Comment: *The JSON could look like this:* (the code following that statement is not JSON)

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not proud of this answer, it would probably work for your needs. It also does not require a browser to have HTML5 local storage.

```
<input type="hidden" id="json_data" />

<script type="text/javascript>
    var theData = [
        {
            id: 1,
            firstName: 'John',
            lastName: 'Hancock',
            pct: 49.5
        },
        // other objects
        {
            id: 6,
            firstName: 'Fred',
            lastName: 'Flintstone',
            pct: 45.8
        }
    ];
    var dataAsJsonString = JSON.stringify(theData);
    $('#json_data').val(dataAsJsonString); // store data in hidden field

    // later on...
    var getDataBackOut = $.parseJSON($('#json_data').val());
    // you can now iterate over the array to find what you need
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = localStorage.getItem("bar");
// ...
localStorage.setItem("bar", foo);
```

[Use HTML5 Local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Comment: HTML5 local storage does have a memory limit of I think 15mb per domain so as long as it is a small json object you'll be fine.